# FORECAST() Oracle BI (OBIEE)

Tags: oracle, dashboard, forecasting, obiee, oracle-bi

please help me how to use forecast() function in oracle bi, I've used all methods to make it work somehow but I couldn't.

These are the errors that I'm getting.

**Error 1:**
Formula syntax is invalid.
[nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. (HY000)

[nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. (HY000)

[nQSError: 23062] Invalid Measure Argument Type specified for FORECAST()

function. Argument type "Table"."Column" should be of type Measure. (HY000)

SQL Issued: SELECT FORECAST("Table"."Column", ("Table"."Column"), 'forecast', 'modelType=arima;numPeriods=%1;predictionInterval=%2', 12, 90) FROM "Table"

**Error 2:**

Invalid Measure Argument Type specified for FORECAST() function. Argument type "Table"."Column" should be of type Measure. (HY000)

SQL Issued: SELECT FORECAST("Table"."Column", ("Table"."Column"), 'forecast', 'modelType=arima;numPeriods=%1;predictionInterval=%2', 12, 90) FROM "CUSTOMER Pqt Agent Detail Plan"
OK (Ignore Error)

**Error 3:**
Formula syntax is invalid.

[nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. (HY000)

[nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. (HY000)

[nQSError: 23062] Invalid Measure Argument Type specified for FORECAST() function. Argument type "Table"."Column" should be of type Measure. (HY000)

SQL Issued: SELECT FORECAST("Table"."Column", ("Table"."Column"), 'forecast', 'modelType=arima;numPeriods=%1;predictionInterval=%2', 1, 9) FROM "Table"."Column"
OK (Ignore Error)

I also tried to typecast my measure column by adding numeric_"Table"."Column" but the it gave me syntax error, I tried every possible combinations but still it didn't work. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

"Argument type "Table"."Column" should be of type Measure."

^--- So give it a measure already! An actual measure with an aggregation rule.

Comment: The first column is actually of type measure, other functions like sum and count are working fine but all the time series functions aren't, I added numeric_ to typecast it somehow but still it doesn't work, can you please write a correct syntax, Thank you.